# Adding a layer of concrete and tiles in the garage

Tags: concrete, flooring, tile, floor, garage

I just wanted to get opinions on my plans to fix the somewhat sunken slab in our garage.

We bought the house two years and (it's about 50 years old) and I have been monitoring the slab since day 1. It has not sunk any further so it's likely that the settling happened a long time ago.

Anyway, the slab is about 2" to 1" lower than where it should be and I am considering the following two options:

1. Add a thin layer on concrete and then install basic by 4/5 PEI rating porcelain tile.
2. Add the concrete layer but top it with 1/2" interlocking vinyl or PVC tile.

The reason go with the porcelain or plastic tiles is basically to avoid the thin concrete layer from peeling or cracking. Btw, I do intend to drill holes every few feet and use some bonding additive to help the two layers of concrete bond.

The question is, will either of my options work?

Answer (score 1):

I would acid etch the old cement with a strong muriatic acid solution to clean and make the surface rough. Then add a adhesive promoter like Moos milk painted on the slab that will help the cement bond and reduce cracking. I have done this on floors as thin as 3/4" and as thick as 2" with good results. With a thin slab a fine aggregate like 1/4" will also help.